# How can I set a default alias in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm just starting with MySQL and I'm sure this is a simple thing but I could not find an answer.

I want to set an alias to the fields of my table in MySQL but I can not find where to do that on phpMyAdmin.

I only find how to set the alias to them when your are doing a query but not a default one.

Comment: There is no default alias. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Where's the point in adding a default alias? I've never heard of such an option. Better rename the column if the name never fits

Comment: Ditto, OP plz give more info.

Comment: @Nico Haase. you are right it would be simplest.

Answer (score 0):

> I only find how to set the alias to them when your are doing a query

Because queries are one of the few places that you can define and reference them (DELETE statements being another).